# Unary operator '++'

Tags: swift, operator-keyword

I am interested and beginning in Swift, but I can't fix that :

```
func countvalue(tableau : [String]){
    var b : Int = 0

    for var b in tableau {
       b++ // Unary operator '++' cannot be applied to an operand of type @lvalue String'
    }

    print("Il y a \(b) valeurs dans ce tableau.")
}
```

Comment: Note that the `++` operator is slated for removal in Swift 3, so it might be a good idea not to get used to using it. :)

Comment: Yes, indeed as @matt said is not recommended use this operator for the accepted proposal of its removal in Swift 3.

Comment: @matt is something due to replace it? If not, what is the better way of incrementing by 1?

Comment: @Fogmeister Swift 3 is removing confusing C-style syntax (including C-style for-loops). If you want to add 1 to something, just add 1 to it.

Comment: @matt hehe, makes sense :D

Answer (score 2):

The `b` in your loop is a different variable than the one outside the loop, and is masking it.  Since `tableau` is an array of `String`s, `b` in the loop is a `String`, and thus cannot be incremented.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is this...

```
func countvalue(tableau : [String]){
    var b : Int = 0

    for _ in tableau {
       // the values in the array are not used so just ignore them with _
       b++ // Unary operator '++' cannot be applied to an operand of type @lvalue String'
    }

    print("Il y a \(b) valeurs dans ce tableau.")
}
```

But the value of `b` will be the same if you do...

```
var b = tableau.count
```

Except this is a lot more efficient as it does not have to iterate every value of the array.

Comment: It isn't "just the same". `count` is _much_ more efficient; it does not have to pass thru all the elements in order to know how many there are.

Comment: @matt indeed. Maybe I should say "the value of b would be the same as doing..." :)

Comment: Alright, thank you very much. My plan was to create a .count like function. :)

Comment: "My plan was to create a .count like function" Understood, and I'm not saying it's not a good exercise! You are clearly learning something by experimenting, and that's great. I'm just saying that in reality you'll never create one that's as good as the existing `count`.